# Is there different types of .svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently learning css and I have encountered some question about the SVG img. I have discovered that some SVG will take up the whole width of webpage if their width or height are not set, while some don’t and have a defined size. What does this property called? Is it related to the design of SVG image? [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDWVD56S2ND)

Also, if I put a SVG which takes up the whole width of webpage into a flex box, the SVG will decrease in size. Why does this happen? Considing that a normal image and a SVG with defined size will not decrease the size in the same situation.[example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDZPK8Y5R5B)(fixed with class = "flex" instead of id).

I am also wondering how does the computer determine what size should the SVG decreased to? I have tried a few SVG(which take whole width) and almost each of them will decreased to a value near 150px x 150px in the flex box.

Comment: You may refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternUnits

Comment: the svg used as image has: the first one a width and a height of 100%. The second one has a width and a height of 300 units

Comment: Thanks for your help! But why does the svg with width and a height of 100% decrease sizes in flex box? These svgs mostly decreased to 150px x 150px

Comment: your svg is not in a flexbox but used inside an img tag , you can only style img then, but not the svg inside (which is not part of the current document) . both svg have the viewbox attribute **and also the width** attribute 100% or 300 (no units  ).  you make it hard for yourself flex + img + svg for the src :(

Comment: in the second example you have an error: 3(three) elements with the same id="flex". Please fix this.

Comment: Hi enxaneta. In example 2, I want to compare the behavior of images in flex boxes, so 3 divs should have the same setting and I gave them same id. I have fixed it by setting 3 divs having same class. That should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

outer `<svg>` elements are replaced elements in CSS/HTML parlance and follow the rules for [replaced element sizing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements)

In particular if replaced elements have no defined size the browser falls back to a size of 300px x 150px, which is likely what you're seeing.

Normal i.e. raster images always have a defined size and are not replaced elements.

See also the [SVG specification for how CSS affects SVG sizing](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewportSpace)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have googled the default 300px x 150px before asking. I was wondering why it is 150px x 150px instead of 300px x 150px. But thanks for your reply

Comment: If they have a viewBox, that establishes an aspect ratio and the browser can then use one attribute to infer the other so I assume it's using the height and the viewBox aspect ratio to infer the width.

Comment: both svg also have the width attribute (100% Vs 300 ) ;)